# How to use metafor if only Cohen's d and dz are available

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am looking for examples or suggestions how to use the R package metafor to conduct a meta-analysis if no descriptive statistics are available, only Cohen's ds and Cohen's dz, alongside the sample size. A few papers relevant report sufficient descriptive statistics so that I can compute Cohen's d or dz, but many unfortunately only report the t-value and sample size, or directly Cohen's d or dz etc. Ideally, I would 'feed' a function with the effect and sample sizes and the function would compute the variance of the effect size, the summary statistics and would allow me to create a forest plot. I am aware that this is possible with the formulas provided in Borenstein et al's (2009) book and rmeta (for the forestplot), but I want to familiarise myself with metafor.

The examples I found assume the ideal case that the authors report all relevant descriptive statistics, which happens unfortunately not that often.

Comment: I would have thought back-calculating the standardised mean difference from t and df or t and p was just a line of code (and actually questions asking for code are off-topic here). Have I misunderstood?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:assembling_data_smd